# Tinkerpop gremlin ignore vertex

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

when I use path in Tinkerpop, I'm trying to ignore several vertices along the path with as() and where(neq()).

```
g.V().out().out().as('a').out().where(neq('a')).path()
```

however, I still cannot ignore the vertex 'a'.
Is there anyway to ignore a specific vertex along a path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should do, although use case is very vague:

```
g.V().out().out().as('a').out().path()
    .map(unfold().where(neq('a')).fold())
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to Tinkerpop and don't know too much which method can do what. Yes you are correct, I will use a more specific case next time.